# SQL Select friends query

Tags: sql, social-networking

I am trying to select the friends of the current user, using a query that returns a list of friends for table 1 row per friendship.

I have a User and a Friends Table:

```
User(UserID, Username)

Friends(IdFirst, IdSecond)
```

Assuming i have the following users: `(1, 'Alex'), (2, 'Ana'), (3, 'Daniel')` and the following friendships: `(1, 2), (1,3), (2,3)`

Up until now I have been using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM User U
LEFT JOIN Friends F
ON U.IdUser = F.IdSecond
WHERE F.IdFirst = *LOGGED USER ID*
```

And it only works if I have mirrored friendships, example: `(1, 2) (2, 1) (1, 3) (3,1)` and I only want to have a single pair for each friendship. If use the above query I only get the list of friends for IdFirst.

I hope I make sense, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a union? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da447/7

```
SELECT * FROM users U
  LEFT JOIN friends F
  ON U.userid = F.idsecond
  WHERE F.idfirst = *LOGGED USER ID*
UNION
SELECT * FROM users U
  LEFT JOIN friends F
  ON U.userid = F.idfirst
  WHERE F.idsecond = *LOGGED USER ID*
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply? Unless you need fields from users which you have not indicated.

```
SELECT idFirst
      ,idSecond 
  FROM Friends
 WHERE IdFirst = *LOGGED USER ID*
    OR IdSecond =*LOGGED USER ID*
```

This means you don't have to have mirrored friendships--and in fact you should not.

EDIT: if you do want the user for the friends you can do it without a union as:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users U
 WHERE UserID <> *LOGGED USER ID*
   AND EXISTS(
               SELECT 1
                 FROM Friends 
                 WHERE (IdFirst = *LOGGED USER ID* AND IdSecond = UserID)
                    OR (IdSecond =*LOGGED USER ID* AND IdFirst = UserID)
             )
```

I'm not sure it better than @BarbaraLaird 's. Though the execution plan looks simpler here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da447/13

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seemed he was trying to get the name of all the current user's friends

Comment: @BarbaraLaird: Certainly could be, it wasn't explicit. If so would obviously need more as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all doing `left join` while filtering from right table is nonsense because left join becomes inner join. Second, you can do this with joins, no need for `union`:

```
select case when u1.Id = @currentUser then u1.Id else u2.Id end as Id,
       case when u1.Id = @currentUser then u1.Name else u2.Name end as Name,
from Friends f
join Users u1 on f.IdFirst u1.Id
join Users u2 on f.IdSecond u2.Id
where u1.Id = @currentUser or u2.Id = @currentUser
```